# Specifying custom linker executable to g++

Tags: gcc, lld

I would like to try the LLVM linker (`lld`) on our project. We use gcc 6, so apparently the `-fuse-ld=lld` flag is not available yet. I don't control the ld executable used by default, so I can't replace it with a symlink. Are there any other options?

The build system we use is make, and linking is done by the compiler, not a direct call to ld.

Comment: To be pedantic, linking is never done by the compiler (it has no idea how to do it). The `gcc` executable you are using is called the compiler driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy workaround is to modify `PATH` environment variable to point to custom `ld` executable (see the example [here](https://github.com/yugr/ld-limiter/blob/master/ld-limit)).

Comment: According to collect2 docs (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Collect2.html), this only works if ld is not hardcoded in gcc during the build, which was the case in my scenario. However, I was able to specify a different compiler and there it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Given the path to the `ld` executable you want is `/path/to/custom/ld`, passing `-B/path/to/custom/` to the compiler driver (`gcc`) should do it. From the GCC manual:

> `-Bprefix`
> This option specifies where to find the executables, libraries, include
> files, and data files of the compiler itself.  The compiler driver program
> runs one or more of the subprograms cpp, cc1, as and **ld**.  It tries
> prefix as a prefix for each program it tries to run, both with and without
> machine/version/ for the corresponding target machine and compiler version.
> For each subprogram to be run, the compiler driver **first tries the -B
> prefix**, if any.

Comment: should be just "-B/path/to/custom/" or "-B=/path/to/custom/", CC will automatically look for ld

Comment: @JayYang good catch, thank you. I'll edit the answer to fix this.