# Rust stdweb fails to compile

Tags: rust, webassembly, rust-cargo

I wanted to get started with the [stdweb](https://github.com/koute/stdweb) library but for some reason my code doesn't compile. Here's the code:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate stdweb;

fn main() {
    stdweb::initialize();

    let message = "Hello, 世界!";
    js! {
        alert( @{message} );
    }

    stdweb::event_loop();
}
```

And here's the error I get when i run `cargo web start --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown`:

```
error: linking with `rust-lld` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "rust-lld" "rust-lld" "-flavor" "wasm" "--no-threads" "-z" "stack-size=1048576" "--stack-first" "--allow-undefined" "--fatal-warnings" "--no-demangle" "--export-dynamic" "--no-entry" "-L" "/home/kuba/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib" "/home/kuba/Projects/rust-snake/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps/rust_snake.16ntzdg2n8bx81q6.rcgu.o" "/home/kuba/Projects/rust-snake/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps/rust_snake.2xfx8uklq7n12q67.rcgu.o" "/home/kuba/Projects/rust-snake/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps/rust_snake.48klqndjiid3k9rj.rcgu.o" "/home/kuba/Projects/rust-snake/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps/rust_snake.48le17nhrmqft97k.rcgu.o" "/home/kuba/Projects/rust-snake/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps/rust_snake.4b580liojrglk551.rcgu.o" "/home/kuba/Projects/rust-snake/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps/rust_snake.4rrrlrglrmdphj5c.rcgu.o" "/home/kuba/Projects/rust-snake/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps/rust_snake.4vuc8rinrzvzrs2v.rcgu.o" "/home/kuba/Projects/rust-snake/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps/rust_snake.50srrlytlsid8m35.rcgu.o" "/home/kuba/Projects/rust-snake/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps/rust_snake.5fgjih7crwhwn4xr.rcgu.o" "/home/kuba/Projects/rust-snake/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps/rust_snake.5fkqw2idrlv7jos5.rcgu.o" "-o" "/home/kuba/Projects/rust-snake/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps/rust_snake.wasm" "--export" "main" "--export" "__web_malloc" "--export" "__web_free" "--export=__heap_base" "--export=__data_end" "/home/kuba/Projects/rust-snake/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps/rust_snake.2l9dobmrlqco0sju.rcgu.o" "--gc-sections" "-O0" "-L" "/home/kuba/Projects/rust-snake/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps" "-L" "/home/kuba/Projects/rust-snake/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/home/kuba/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib" "/home/kuba/Projects/rust-snake/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps/libstdweb-ef476852d27a12c5.rlib" "/home/kuba/Projects/rust-snake/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps/libdiscard-a83cebb0a142eb8f.rlib" "/home/kuba/Projects/rust-snake/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps/libstdweb_internal_runtime-0bce6e61d1817cf7.rlib" "/home/kuba/Projects/rust-snake/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps/libserde_json-1c98a67e94d08af3.rlib" "/home/kuba/Projects/rust-snake/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps/libryu-322b81c9b49f7e9f.rlib" "/home/kuba/Projects/rust-snake/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps/libitoa-a7c2d7644820b152.rlib" "/home/kuba/Projects/rust-snake/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/deps/libserde-c2f4e30465155451.rlib" "/home/kuba/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/libstd-9c867bc4c16ee4c2.rlib" "/home/kuba/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/libpanic_abort-ed0cd729c2f3d142.rlib" "/home/kuba/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/libdlmalloc-030f419e714a0cc6.rlib" "/home/kuba/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/libhashbrown-a12a1f881dba75e1.rlib" "/home/kuba/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-35aa06e58878157c.rlib" "/home/kuba/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/libbacktrace-6636ad5f40fe0c6e.rlib" "/home/kuba/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/librustc_demangle-3c1019358081106e.rlib" "/home/kuba/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/libunwind-b93526bae6789131.rlib" "/home/kuba/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/libcfg_if-12a659b7ffc8c645.rlib" "/home/kuba/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/liblibc-62025a1d48e0630e.rlib" "/home/kuba/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/liballoc-80234d57a1442351.rlib" "/home/kuba/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-d429e78abfaecaef.rlib" "/home/kuba/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/libcore-c485e95495d6739c.rlib" "/home/kuba/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/libcompiler_builtins-53d1b7f6a2bd6c6f.rlib" "-fuse-ld=gold"
  = note: rust-lld: error: unknown argument: -fuse-ld=gold


error: aborting due to previous error
error: could not compile `rust-snake`.
```

Some additional info I think might be useful:

cargo version: `cargo 1.41.0-nightly (626f0f40e 2019-12-03)`
insides of ~/.cargo/config:

```
[target.arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf]
linker = "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-7"
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Edit: I'm using "elementary os" (basicly ubuntu with cooler ui). And trying to build on stable gives me exactly the same error.

Edit2: `rustup show` returns

```
rustup home:  /home/kuba/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.40.0 (73528e339 2019-12-16)
```

Edit3: `cargo-web --version` returns `cargo-web 0.6.26`

Comment: On what platform are you building the project? Are you tied to that nightly version of the compiler?

Comment: @E_net4thesafedownvoter I build on linux. To be precise its "elementary os" which is basicly just ubuntu with cooler ui but systemwise everything works like on ubuntu. Could you explain what do you mean by "tied to"? Cheers

Comment: As in, do you really need to use that version of the Rust compiler? It could be that you just stumbled upon a particular nightly toolchain which doesn't work well with stdweb. Also, don't forget to edit your question with those details.

Answer (score 1):

Your linker or compiler settings are not set correctly, or changed somehow.

> error: unknown argument: -fuse-ld=gold

Remove the [gold linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_(linker)) flag: `-fuse-ld=gold` from your `RUSTFLAGS`, `LD` environmental variables or the compiler options.

Use verbose flag (`-v` or `--verbose`) to see verbose output:

```sh
cargo web build -v --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown
```

WebAssembly is fast, safe, **portable**, and part of the open Web platform.
So the WebAssembly is **platform independent** (You don't need to compile it to `ARM`, and it is virtual machine based so you need a host to run WebAssembly, e.g. inside a web browser JavaScript VM for WebAssembly. Also there is [WASI: WebAssembly System Interface](https://github.com/bytecodealliance/wasmtime/blob/master/docs/WASI-overview.md)).

Since it is **portable**:
You may build it using your working compiler on any machine and then just copy `.wasm` file(s) to the target web server machine.

---

To start a web hello world sample from scratch:

```sh
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown

# https://github.com/koute/stdweb
cargo search cargo-web
# cargo-web = "0.6.26"          # A Cargo subcommand for the client-side Web
# cargo install cargo-web --version 0.6.26
cargo install cargo-web
file ~/.cargo/bin/cargo-web
cargo-web --version
# cargo-web 0.6.26

# create new project e.g. "123stdweb-rs-js"
cargo new 123stdweb-rs-js
cd 123stdweb-rs-js

cargo search stdweb
```

Add to Cargo.toml file end after `[dependencies]`:

```
stdweb = "0.4.20"  # A standard library for the client-side Web
```

`main.rs` file:

```
use stdweb;
use stdweb::js;

fn main() {
    stdweb::initialize();
    let message = "Hello from stdweb.";
    let result = js! {
        alert( @{message} );
        return 2 + 2 * 2;
    };
    println!("2 + 2 * 2 = {:?}", result);
    stdweb::event_loop();
}
```

Build and run web server to serve `target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/stdweb-rs-js.js`:

```sh
# Compile to WebAssembly using Rust's native WebAssembly backend:
cargo web start --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown
```

Open your web browser http://localhost:8000:

```sh
firefox http://localhost:8000
```

Done.

---

You may release build:

```
cargo web build --release --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown
mkdir static
cp target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/stdweb-rs-js.js ./static/
cp target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/stdweb-rs-js.wasm ./static/
```

Now you may serve `stdweb-rs-js.js` and `stdweb-rs-js.wasm` files using your favorite static web server e.g. `python3 -m http.server 8080` using simple `./static/index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Right click <b>Inspect</b> then click <b>Console</b> tab
    <hr />

    <script src="stdweb-rs-js.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

That's all.

---

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sadly, after following all steps I still get the same error :(

Comment: And I don't think its my fault since I got it to work with no problems on my windows machine

Comment: Yes it does. I think it's just cargo web that's failing.

Comment: Building the repository you linked fails with the same error as the original question

Comment: Hey i tried few things and finally thanks to you I found out that i can make it work by using "RUSTFLAGS='-C linker=rust-lld' cargo web start --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown". Is there any way I could make it do that by default?

Comment: Also I dont have a "LD" enviroment variable and I dont know how to change compiler options but if you could explain maybe that's a more elegant solution

Comment: You should find -fuse-ld=gold and remove it. Check this commands first [echo $RUSTFLAGS] [env] [echo $LDFLAGS].
search for -fuse-ld or LDFLAGS on your environment variables [search for LDFLAGS here too](https://lld.llvm.org/), [Configuration](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html), [Environment](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html), [RUSTFLAGS](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/4423), [linker](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/52362), [custom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55628741/specifying-custom-linker-executable-to-g).

Comment: Ok I found it! For some reason my RUSTFLAGS enviroment variable was set to "-C link-args='-fuse-ld=gold'" by default. I have no idea why did it do that but after clearing RUSTFLAGS in /etc/enviroment everything works perfectly fine. Thanks for help :)